# Can someone who is born a psychopath acquire empathy through conditioning and neuroplasticity?

Tags: neuroscience

Are there any studies of conditioning and neuroplasticity being used to bring back empathy to psychopaths?

Comment: What do you mean by use of neuroplasticity?